# Jquery Checkbox custom event does not return stable result

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi I'm working on a custom blogsite I have a working script here for my checkbox. But my checkbox does not have the attrib `checked` by default because my page displays first the actual article then the checkbox is labeled as "edit" so when a user clicks on it the article will be loaded on my textarea(It has TinyMCE plugin for editing purpose) the user can now edit the article.. This will be used to check if someone is editing it already FYI

Here is my script:

```
$("#edit").on('change', function(e){
        $("#viewmode").toggle(function(){
                    $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'includes/edittyp.php',
              data: "flag="+0,
              success: function (status) { }
                });
        });
        $("#viewmode").toggleClass('display: none' );
        $("#editmode").toggle(function(){

                $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'includes/edittyp.php',
              data: "flag="+1,
              success: function (status) { }
                });
        });
        $("#editmode").toggleClass('display: block' );
```

My issue is this script updates the flag to 1 whenever `$("#editmode")` is toggled and it updates to 0 whenever  `$("#viewmode")` is also clicked but this works only once because after I refreshed the page the `viewmode` returns 1 and `editmode` returns 0 or it does not change at all.. Can someone please point out where did I go wrong or are there other way/s on how can achieve this

Thanks

Comment: So if user A is reading the article, any number of other users can read it. But if user A is editing the article, no one else can read/edit it? It seems you're blocking the 'read' server-side, right?

Comment: Is this fiddle the type of functionality you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/3DZYJ/

Comment: yeah if someone is editing a certain article other users who are viewing it cant edit it unless that user moves from other page or saves it.. I'll try the jsfiddle that you have provided